# LARAVEL - Displaying images from the storage folder

Tags: php, image, laravel, upload, controllers

I'm new to Laravel and was wondering if someone can help me out with a simple image upload.

I have a form that allows a user to create a profile and upload and avatar for their profile during the process. This all works perfectly. Here is the code from my controller:

```
if (request()->hasFile('avatar')) {

        $file = request()->file('avatar');

        $file->storeAs('avatars/' . auth()->id(), 'avatar.jpg');
    }
```

The image is saved within storage/app/avatars/USER-ID/avatar.jpg

I'm not sure how to display the image from this folder. I've looked for solutions but I am unable to use `php artisan storage:link` as it is not my server. How do I go about this without using the storage link? Can I create a link manually?

If someone could explain a solution to me that would be perfect!

Just ask if you need any code snippets.

Thanks!

Comment: did you get it?

Comment: @developernator I haven't worked it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to access the protected files using a route the plugs into a controller that can access the files and pass it to the view.

I would also recommend using the package `intervention/image` it can be installed by

`composer require intervention/image`

See below to on accessing the image:

// Your route in `web.php`

```
// Public route to show user avatar
Route::get('avatars/{id}/{image}', [
    'uses'      => 'TheNameOfYourController@userProfileAvatar'
]);
```

// In your controller file. In this example according the name of what we have above it would be `userProfileAvatar()`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Image;

class TheNameOfYourController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Show user avatar
     *
     * @param $id
     * @param $image
     * @return string
     */
    public function userProfileAvatar($id, $image)
    {
        return Image::make(storage_path() . '/avatars/' . $id . '/' . $image)->response();
    }

}
```

// Your blade view to display the image

```
<img src="images/profile/{{ \Auth::user()->id }}/avatar.jpg" alt="{{ \Auth::user()->name }}">
```

Here are some references but this intances that go one step further and save the file path the database upon upload:

// Route Example

- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/routes/web.php

// Controller Example

- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ProfilesController.php

// View Examples

- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/resources/views/profiles/show.blade.php
- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/resources/views/profiles/edit.blade.php
- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/resources/views/partials/nav.blade.php

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, you've been a huge help! The references are fantastic too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you don't have access to the server to create a symlink, you need to create a route that returns the image as response.

Something like that:

```
Route::get('storage/{filename}', function ($filename) 
{
   $path = storage_path('avatars/' . $filename);

   if (!File::exists($path)) {
      abort(404);
   }

   $file = File::get($path);
   $type = File::mimeType($path);

   $response = Response::make($file, 200);
   $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

   return $response;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a symbolic link which will connect `storage/app` and `public/img` directories, for example:

```
ln -s /home/laravel/public/img /home/laravel/storage/app
```

Then just use `asset()` helper to generate a link:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/avatars/'.auth()->id().'/avatar.jpg') }}">
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a link myself? I don't have access to command line